# what is the most efficient way of getting objects from list based on field of class

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I have an `ArrayList` of type `Custome`r which contains fields suhc as `id`, `name` and `age`.
Currently, to find a customer with a given `id`, I am looping through the entire list and using `getID`. However, this seems to be an expensive operation.

```
public Customer findCustomer(List customers, String id) {
    for (Customer customer : customers) {
        if (customer.getId().equals("23")
                return customer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't think , you have any other better way except changing datastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the code much more elegant, but it will still be an O(n) operation that in the worst case will still go over the entire list:

```
return customers.stream().filter(c -> c.getId().equals(id)).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

If you want a better performing solution, you'll need a different data structure. A `Map` from the ID to the customer object would enable you to retrieve a customer by its ID as an O(1) operation.

Comment: So i should change the data structure like below : 
 Map<String, Person> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("23", new Person("23", "dk", "1504993"));        System.out.println(map.get("22").toString());

Comment: @darshankamat yup, that's it!